# Install debian app to a USB thumb drive, and run it from there

Tags: 18.04

Ubuntu 18.04.

I have the debian file for an application (web browser).

How do I install that application to a USB thumb drive, such that when I insert the drive into a computer running Ubuntu I can run the application from that thumb drive?

Comment: The user does not get to choose where a deb package installs to. Pick a different (non-deb) installation method for a non-standard location.

Comment: What you want is basically covered in https://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-do-i-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file Use /media/mountpoint/ as the installation path for the TAR.GZ version of the browser. A DEB is the wrong archive for this.